# Referencing a workbook whose file name changes consistently - solution suggestions?

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA here.
At work I am creating a macro that can compile and format data from a report we get monthly and the file name changes.
Since the name changes, instead of having to go into VBE and changing the name from there, is there a user form I might be able to create that allows me to type in the name of the workbook and it will be able to insert it into the script?

What I have so far:

```
Sub tester()

Dim wbName As String
wbName = Application.InputBox("What is the workbook name?")
If Right(wbName, 4) <> ".xls" Then wbName = wbName + ".xls"
Set mainWB = Workbooks(wbName)

Dim copyThis As Range, pasteThis As Range

Set copyThis = mainWB.Worksheets(2).Columns("F")
Set pasteThis = Workbooks("VBA Workbook.xlsm").Worksheeets(1).Columns("A")

copyThis.Copy Destination:=pasteThis

End Sub
```

The workbook name will change month to month.

Alternative solutions are welcomed

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your macro is in `Personal.xlsb`, and you have the workbook you need to reference as the `ActiveWorkbook`, you can just do:

```
Dim mainWB as Workbook
Set mainWB = ActiveWorkbook
```

Then you'd just use `mainWB` as the reference, so:

```
mainWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
```

Or if you want the user to input the WB name:

```
Dim wbName as String
wbName = Application.InputBox("What is the workbook name?")
If right(wbName, 4) <> ".xls" Then wbName = wbName + ".xls"
Set mainWB = Workbooks(wbName)
...
```

...And you'd probably want to add error handling in the `InputBox()` case, if the user types a name that isn't correct.

Comment: Thanks! This is insightful. Since the activeworkbook is referenced, what if I have two workbooks and I want to reference the second one?

Comment: @patriciajlim you can use the input method, or, just click into/out of a cell in the workbook you want as active then run the sub

Comment: I have tried the code, however am getting an error that suggests the subscript is out of range.  ````Set mainWB = Workbooks(wbName)```` is highlighted as the line with the error. I have updated the code above, could you help me identify what might be wrong?

Comment: @patriciajlim what is `wbName` when it throws the error? (Add `Debug.print wbName` before the `Set wbName ...` line) you might have to include the path to that workbook.